# How to remove Start Menu Layer on my Desktop

Tags: windows-10, desktop, start-menu, hp-laptop, tablet-mode

[image]

I had pretty much the default before. As you can see, all my icons have disappeared and I now have a "back" button. Clicking the windows icon does nothing, and on top of that, I can't minimize or resize any windows I have open.

I've tried restarting my computer to no avail! So what's gone wrong?

Comment: Sure it's not a screenshot as desktop background?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're in tablet mode. Click the **Notification Icon** on the far right of your taskbar. Then click **tablet mode** to get out of tablet mode.